# Correct way to unwrap an Optional Integer in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

What is the correct way to set `fullLength` here?

```
var index = foo.index(foo.startIndex, offsetBy: SOME_NUM)
let length = Int(foo.substring(to: index))

if let fullLength = length? + SOME_NUM {
  return
}
```

The problem here is `length?` is an Optional. I had this working with:

`fullLength = length! + SOME_NUM`, but I don't want to risk using `!` in the event `length` is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it as

```
if let length = length {
    let fullLength = length + SOME_NUM
}
```

Comment: SO should have a "so and so is typing an answer" so that people don't write the exact same thing 15 seconds apart. :-p

Comment: Yeah, that definitely happens quite often. Having faster internet on my side would probably help as well :D

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of nil-Coalescing operator.To help you with understanding nil-Coalescing operator let us take an example, which will solve your problem too.The nil-coalescing operator '??' in a ?? b unwraps an optional a if it contains a value or returns a default type b if a is nil. It is shorthand for

```
    a != nil ? a! : b
```

Now coming to your question

```
    var index = foo.index(foo.startIndex, offsetBy: SOME_NUM)
    let length = Int(foo.substring(to: index))
    let someDefaultValue = 0 

    let fullLength = length ?? someDefaultValue + SOME_NUM
    // or to be precise , you can also 
    //replace someDefaultValue with 0 in above code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let length = length
{
    fullLength = length + SOME_NUM
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
let index = foo.index(foo.startIndex, offsetBy: SOME_NUM)

guard let length = Int(foo.substring(to: index)) else {
    //show error
    //return reasonable value for error
}

let fullLength = length + SOME_NUM
```

This way approaches the problem as `length` being a valid number (not nil) as a precondition of the execution of the rest of the code.